Why does the density of saturated $\rm NaCl$ and $\rm H_2O$ saline increases after reaching 90 Celcius? Values from www.omnicalculator.com
Values are obtained from www.omnicalculator.com/physics/water-density. The saline is always at maximum  $\rm NaCl$ saturation at all temperatures.


Isn't this more for Chemistry SE?

I was trying to focus on the physical aspects/properties of saline.
But its kind of a mix of both chemistry and physics
